# How to find the number of paths between two vertices of a certain length?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I need to find the number of paths (not necessarily simple) between s and t (2 fixed vertices), length at most  in an unweighted graph. With the time: ().

If I understand correctly for k < E, I can use a modified bfs.
But what do we do for very large k?

Comment: A useful [result](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers): If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph $G$, the number of paths of length $n$ from a vertex $i$ to a vertex $j$ in $G$ is given by the $i,j$ entry of $A^n$.